# Connection With Oracle Data base with VS 2008

Tags: .net, oracle, connectivity

I am using 10g Oracle client , 
Database server connectivity is proper

I am Using 2.0 or 3.5 .Net Framework to connect oracle database on same server with following Coce :--

```
 string connectionString = "Data Source=nf5;User ID=nfadmin;Password=nfadmin;Min Pool  Size=2;Max Pool Size=500;Connection Lifetime=120;pooling=true;";

Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection conn = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        conn.Open();
```

**I am able to connect with 2.0 (VS-2005) Framework successfully**

**BuT Not able to connect with 3.5 (VS-2008) Framework with following Error on the Line conn.Open(); on same server**

**ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

Please suggest ,

Regards
Saurabh

Comment: You are missing the SID / Service name and other very important parts of the connection string. Please go to http://www.connectionstrings.com/ and find a proper connection string for Oracle database. Apart from this, are you able to connect to Oracle DB using SQL Developer or other SQL editor?